# checkboxlist when i do unchecked , it will work true

Tags: c#, checkboxlist

```
 void calculate()
 {
     total = 0.0; 
     price = 0.0;
     calori = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < AdditionsListBox.Items.Count; i++)
     {
         if (AdditionsListBox.GetItemChecked(i) == true)
         {
             price = price + pricearray[milkindex * 3 + i];
             calori = calori + caloriarray[milkindex * 3 + i];
         }
     }
     total = Convert.ToInt16(numericUpDown5.Value)* price;
     totalTextbox.Text = price.ToString();
     UnitCaloriTextbox.Text = calori.ToString();
     totalTextbox.Text = total.ToString();
 }
```

when i check, AdditionsListBox.GetItemChecked(i) it is not true but when i do uncheck on item ,it will give me true where is my mistake ? 
for example i checked item but it doesnt calculate but when i do uncheck item it calculate correctly

Comment: When is this method called? Is it possible, that you call it on a click event (or something like that), which is executed before the checked state has acually changed?

Answer (score 0):

There are two selection behaviours in `checkedlistbox`

1.`Selecting` an item.
2.`Checking` an item.

**Points to remember:**
1.when you call `GetItemChecked()` function it will only return whether item is checked or not ,but not selected or not. see the below Image.

[image: CheckedListBox Behaviour]

2.`GetItemChecked(i)` function in your code iterates through out the whole Items of `CheckedListBox`, so you have ensure to that whether `GetItemChecked(i)` returning true or not for your item `i` but not for all items.

3.from coding point of view you don't need to change anything.

As these are my assumption if you are still getting the problem even after, please let me know.